# Отправка запроса VK в обход API

Tags: php, вконтакте, curl

Я написал php, который логинится вк и получает страницу, но я не могу понять как с помощью cURL я могу отправить прямой запрос (в обход API), чтобы получить JSON с айдишниками друзей.

```
function getFriends(){
$url = 'https://vk.com/?act=filter_friends&age_from=18&age_to=0&al=1&al_ad=0&city=0&sex=1&uid=5008261121';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) { 
    print curl_error($ch); 
 } 
curl_close($ch);
var_dump(json_decode($result, true));
}
getFriends();
?>
```

Данный код возвращает NULL. Я должен добавить какие-то параметры к запросу?

Comment: я бы silenium использовал. там есть веб драйвер даже для php

Comment: Я пишу веб-бота, мне нужна собственная реализация, к сожалению.

Comment: Вы рофлите? Это всего-лишь библиотека. Вы на чистом коде пишите всегда только? :D

Comment: Попытаться CURL'ом вытащить данные напрямую — моветон. Для этого нужно использовать headless-браузеры. Прогуглите, например, headless chrome, phantomjs, silenium. Нужны они для того, чтобы инициализировать js сайта, ибо при добавлении любого нового параметра запроса со стороны вк, который генерится в js и обязателен для бэка, вы сразу же получите ошибку через CURL.

Comment: Вот возможный вариант https://github.com/chrome-php/headless-chromium-php